# How to get the Datum from P2

Tags: sql, lag

```
SELECT P1.Jaar, P1.Week, P1.Datum, P1.Meter, (SELECT MAX(Meter)
     FROM Tabel1 AS P2
     WHERE P2.jaar = P1.jaar
     AND   P2.[Meter] < P1.[Meter]) AS Previous, P1.[Meter]-[Previous] AS Verbruik
FROM Tabel1 AS P1
ORDER BY P1.Datum DESC;
```

How i get the MAX Datum from P2 into the datagridvieuw..

Comment: Above the question editor box, the `99` button is for quoting, the `{}` is what you need to click to format code

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
P1.[Meter]-[Previous] AS Verbruik
```

We can never reference a column created in the current SELECT block, from the current SELECT block

```
SELECT
  1 + 2 as a,
  a + 3 as b     --no, it doesn't work
FROM 
  ...
```

If you want to do it, you either repeat the operation:

```
SELECT P1.Jaar, P1.Week, P1.Datum, P1.Meter, (SELECT MAX(Meter)
     FROM Tabel1 AS P2
     WHERE P2.jaar = P1.jaar
     AND   P2.[Meter] < P1.[Meter]) AS Previous, P1.[Meter]-(SELECT MAX(Meter)
     FROM Tabel1 AS P2
     WHERE P2.jaar = P1.jaar
     AND   P2.[Meter] < P1.[Meter]) AS Verbruik
FROM Tabel1 AS P1
ORDER BY P1.Datum DESC;
```

Or you do the query earlier:

```
--if the DB supports WITH
WITH t1pre AS (
  SELECT P1.Jaar, P1.Week, P1.Datum, P1.Meter, (SELECT MAX(Meter)
     FROM Tabel1 AS P2
     WHERE P2.jaar = P1.jaar
     AND   P2.[Meter] < P1.[Meter]) AS Previous
  FROM Tabel1 AS P1
)

SELECT *, Meter-Previous  AS Verbruik FROM t1pre
ORDER BY Datum DESC
```

```
--if the DB doesn't do WITH
SELECT *, Meter-Previous  AS Verbruik
FROM (
  SELECT P1.Jaar, P1.Week, P1.Datum, P1.Meter, (SELECT MAX(Meter)
     FROM Tabel1 AS P2
     WHERE P2.jaar = P1.jaar
     AND   P2.[Meter] < P1.[Meter]) AS Previous 
  FROM Tabel1 AS P1
) t1pre
ORDER BY Datum DESC
```

Or you use an alternative strategy, such as LAG (`LAG(Meter) OVER(PARTITION BY Jaar ORDER BY Meter)`?), or joining the tables together so their records are off by one and thus the prev value and the current are on the same row, or some other potentially DB specific provision (last resort imho)

Comment: I want to get the datum with the reference of the Previous result.